# Is GETBULK snmp call available from php?

Tags: php, snmp

I'd like to use GETBULK snmp query from php scripts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

snmp2_real_walk uses getBulkRequest but may cause problems and isn't very configurable... just an FYI.

Source: Two days of debugging why snmp2_real_walk wasn't working for a particular host ( turns out it was because the return packets were too big... I was using wireshark to capture the data).

Answer (score 1):

try this:
http://www.emarksoft.com/snmp-examples/php-snmp-getbulk.htm

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, this is not possible through the native PHP SNMP support.  The various "walk" functions *may* use GETBULK internally (I am not certain on this), but they certainly do *not* expose that functionality (for example, the ability to set the repetitions and such).